# MongoDB geospatial difference between $near and $within

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

What is the difference between `$near` and `$within`?

```
db.geodata.find({ "loc" : { "$within" : { "$center" : [ [ 12.91365 , 77.59395] , 4]}}}).limit(10);

db.geodata.find({ "loc" : { "$near" : [ 12.91365 , 77.59395] , "$maxDistance" : 4}}).limit(10);
```

Can anyone explain in detail?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The main differences are

- `$near` sorts based on distance from a point; `$geoWithin` tests for containment in a polygon or multipolygon with GeoJSON coordinates, or containment in one of a set of shapes for 2d coordinates
- `$near` returns document from nearest to farthest and any other order requires in-memory sorting; `$geoWithin` can be used with other sort indexes
- `$near` requires a geospatial index; `$geoWithin` performs better with one but does not require it
- `$near` is not supported in sharded clusters - you have to use the `geonear` command or`$geoNear` aggregation stage instead

Also check out the documentation for [$near](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) and [$geoWithin](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/).

Comment: "Starting in MongoDB 4.0, $near queries are supported for sharded collections." - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/#sharded-collections